# WordPress MySQL password decryption

Tags: mysql, wordpress, encryption, passwords

I forgot my MySQL password and all I found was this in my WordPress log.

> 8dFZMenSNfw3gyCo

Is there a way to decrypt this?

Comment: which os are you using?

Answer (score 2):

it's not going to be possible to easily retrieve them.

Just reset them with new passwords.
Run your mysql server in safe mode.you can change mysql password then.

https://in.godaddy.com/help/reset-your-root-mysql-password-linux-17548

Answer (score 0):

WordPress password can not be decrypted, algorithm is "one way".

You could fix creating a new admin user with a different email via FTP as described in this tutorial: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-in-wordpress-using-ftp/

Then with the new user you can log in and reset your password.

Answer (score 0):

Re-setting the password is going to be your easiest fix for the issue here, but for completeness let's discuss decrypting it.

Let's assume your wordpress installation is using `wp_hash_password` as described [in the reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password), and what you have posted is the hash from the database (although it doesn't really look like it should).

You can compare this hash to hashes of password guesses to figure out if those guesses are your password... something like...

```
<?php
$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);

$password_hashed = '8dFZMenSNfw3gyCo';
$plain_password = 'myPasswordGuess';

if($wp_hasher->CheckPassword($plain_password, $password_hashed)) {
    echo "YES, Matched";
} else {
    echo "No, Wrong Password";
}
?>
```

You can do this many times in order to perform a brute-force attack on your password.

Note that this needs to be run on your hosting server, so that `CheckPassword` can get the correct [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) for the given password guess.